# Spring transaction by connecting to multiple databases

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, transactions

I am trying to work on a small program where I can connect to multiple databases using Spring and trying to use Spring transactions by deploying my web-application on weblogic server. The problem is that the transaction management is not working properly. I am trying to insert records in 2 databases, the first one inserts without throwing any exceptions, where as the second insert query is written such that it throws an exception. Ideally in this situation the transaction should rollback but the first transaction is committed without any issues.

Here is my **spring-config.xml** file

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.examples" />

<!-- Database1 -->

<bean id="db1DataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb1" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>

<!-- Database2 -->

<bean id="db2DataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb2" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />
<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager" />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

This is my controller:

```
@Controller
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    private CommonEmployeeService commonService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/employee", method = GET)
    public String showPersonListForGivenAge(
            @RequestParam(value = "id") int id,
            @RequestParam(value = "name") String name,
            @RequestParam(value = "email") String email,
            Map<String, Object> model) {

        Employee e = new Employee(id,name);
        EmployeeDetails details = new EmployeeDetails(id,email);

        commonService.insert(e, details);

        return "welcome";
    }
}
```

This is my common service:

```
@Service
public class CommonEmployeeService {

    @Autowired
    EmployeeDetailsService detailsService;

    @Autowired
    EmployeeService service;


    @Transactional
    public boolean insert(Employee e, EmployeeDetails details) {
        service.insert(e);
        detailsService.insert(details);
        return true;
    }
}
```

These are my other services:

**EmployeeService.java**

```
@Service

public class EmployeeService {

    @Autowired
    EmployeeDao dao;

    //@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public boolean insert(Employee e) {
        return dao.insert(e);
    }
}
```

**EmployeeDetailsService.java** -- The DAO in this service throws `NullPointerException`

```
@Service
public class EmployeeDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    EmployeeDetailsDao dao;

    //@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public boolean insert(EmployeeDetails e) {
        return dao.insert(e);
    }

}
```

**Update:** Adding Dao Classes:

EmployeeDao.java:

```
@Repository
public class EmployeeDao {

    JdbcTemplate template;

    @Resource(name = "db1DataSource")
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.template = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    public boolean insert(Employee e) {
        int cnt = template.update("insert into Employee values(?,?)",
                e.getId(), e.getName());
        if (cnt > 0) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

EmployeeDetailsDao.java

```
@Repository
public class EmployeeDetailsDao {

    JdbcTemplate template;

    @Resource(name = "db2DataSource")
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.template = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    public boolean insert(EmployeeDetails e) {
        if(e != null){
            throw new NullPointerException();   
        }

        int cnt = template.update("insert into EmployeeDetails values(?,?)",
                e.getId(), e.getEmail());
        if (cnt > 0) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where you declared your `EmployeeDetailsDao` and `EmployeeDao ` and your transaction manager?

Comment: @Arpit, added my dao classes, I am using `JtaTransactionManager`, please check my  spring config file, it is there.

Comment: You are using JTA without being in a JTA environment, that isn't going to work. You are basically running without transactions, meaning each statements runs in it own transaction. For it to work you need to have your datasources to be XA capable and not a plain datasource (what it is right now).

Comment: @M.Deinum, Thanks for commenting, can you please tel me what changes need to be done to fix the issue? I have never worked on XA earlier

Comment: Judging from your post you are on web logic. First instead of `JtaTransactionManager` use `<tx:jaa-transaction-manager />` next instead of locally configured datasources, create them as XA resources in web logic and in your application do a JNDI lookup for the datasources.

Comment: @M.Deinum, I have configured JNDI on weblogic server and also changed the transaction configuration to  `<tx:jta-transaction-manager />` but still I see same issue. Can you please tell me what else I should change?

Comment: as long as you aren't doing a lookup but using a local database config it isn't going to work. Also are you using the correct `@Transactional` the spring one? And you might need to specify `proxy-target-class="true"` on `<tx;annotation-driven />`.

Comment: @M.Deinum, I am using `jndi-lookup ` in my config file, let me see if there is anything wrong with my jndi settings.

Comment: And are both datasources XA capable? You are using MySQL are you using transactional tables? If the table type is MyISAM there is no transaction support.

Comment: @M.Deinum, it is working now. I have reverted the change for `<tx:jta-transaction-manager />`  and now everything works good. Thanks a lot. But can you please tell me when to go for `<tx:jta-transaction-manager />`, so I can use it when needed.

Comment: `tx:jta-transaction-manager` is a convenience tag it detects the server you are running on and based on that decided which specific `JtaTransactionManager` to use (there are some servers which require a specific one). If there isn't a specific one the default `JtaTransactionManager` is used.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding below in `spring-config.xml`:

```
<context:component-scan base-package=“your.packagename.contatining.EmployeeDetailsDao” />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

and changing `@Transactional` in your `CommonEmployeeService` with `@Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class, propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)` as below

```
@Service
public class CommonEmployeeService {

    @Autowired
    EmployeeDetailsService detailsService;

    @Autowired
    EmployeeService service;

@Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class, propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public boolean insert(Employee e, EmployeeDetails details) {
        service.insert(e);
        detailsService.insert(details);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Arpit, tried your, getting same exception. Component scan was already there in my config file (please see updated config file in my question). Regarding `@Transactional` by default spring rollbacks a transaction on runtime exceptions and default propagation behavior is `required`, so adding these changes will not solve my issue I guess.

Comment: Tried just now, getting same issue

Comment: Is `JdbcTemplate template;` in `EmployeeDao` class is null as well?

Comment: No, it is not null. I am throwing NullPointerException intensionally to see the behaviour

Comment: Might this will help you : http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/spring-jta-multiple-resource-transactions-in-tomcat-with-atomikos-example